Unable to Install Wormhole's NTT CLI
Unable to install Wormhole's new NTT CLI. I'm running this on Ubuntu. I have Bun installed, but still getting the error message. Should I update the node version to fix this?
Here is the CLI:
curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wormhole-foundation/example-native-token-transfers/main/cli/install.sh | bash
This is the error message:
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:317:18)
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:517:28)
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:292:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /root/.ntt-cli/.checkout/node_modules/bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v18.19.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.2.0
gyp ERR! not ok

error: install script from "bufferutil" exited with 1

